# Project can detect import statement, but won't use it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm currently trying to use rhino to do some web scraping (I needed to use Casperjs because of React). So what I did was add the source files to a jar file, and put that in an existing library that I am using without any issues. All of the previous classes can access all that I need in that library. However, this Rhino jar is giving me issues.

I've tried all that I know how to do, making the jar in a million different ways and such. Currently, I just made a jar out of the main package structure (which is org.mozilla and then splits into classpath and JavaScript). The import statement in the class that I want to use detects that "org.mozilla.javascript.*" is valid, and has no issues with it. But the import is unused.

So the first item that I need to import resources for is "Context", of which there is a corresponding "Context.java" class in that jar file. However, when I open up that class to take a look to see what it does, that class can't find any other class that it links to within it's own package. All of the imports within Context.java result in "cannot resolve symbol".

I'm assuming this is an issue in which I did something incorrectly, but I can't say that I even know enough to know how to resolve this at this point. Sorry if the picture leave out details, but there are probably a few hundred Java classes in the library I'm trying to use, so I am only able to fit in screen like 1 or 2 at a time, so I cropped them smaller just so you wouldn't have to look through hundreds to find two classes in the list that aren't imported correctly.

[Java Class that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQnjX.png) and [Context.java from library with imports not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMeSt.png)

Comment: [Possible similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+intellij+import+cannot+resolve+symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "Context.java" file in a jar file, it looks like you are doing it completely wrong. In short, to run a Java program that uses some library from a jar you need a compiled version of the library classes there (*.class files), not the sources.

Java is not JavaScript and is not similar or related to it, the development process is different. To learn the right way I recommend to start with Java tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
Read there the "Covering the basics" trail, "Getting started", "Learning language" and "Deployment" chapters.

Once you have an idea of what JAR is, check this Maven tutorial:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info. That should hopefully get me going in the right direction. I've used Java quite a bit now in terms of making my own code, and I am quite comfortable with it in that regard, but I am very new when it comes to libraries, jar files, Maven and etc. But more importantly, you showed me exactly what the issue was. I was comparing my working library files to the non-working one, and I didn't notice the .class vs .java. Thank you.